# How can get the data from the foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to get the vendor information against the category id,means when someone select the category all vendor's information against the category should be display,but when i call the url it show the error

' Cannot use QuerySet for "VendorCategory": Use a QuerySet for "Vendor" '.

how can i get the vendor information

Model.py

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     Contact_No = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


class VendorCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

View.py

```
class All_Vendor(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'purchase/allVendor.html'

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         categories = categoryModel.objects.all()
         categoryId = self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory')
         vendorselect = VendorCategory.objects.filter(category_id=categoryId)
         vendor_id = VendorCategory.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendorselect)
         vendors = vendorModel.objects.get(id=vendor_id)
         args = {'categories': categories, 'selectedCategory': categoryId, 'vendorselect': vendorselect, 'vendors': vendors}
         return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Template

```
{% block content%}

    <form method="get">

        <label>
             <select name="SelectCategory">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected> Select Category</option>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option value={{ category.id }}>
                {{ category.name }}
            </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
    {% for vendor in vendorselect %}
        {{ vendor.id }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
class All_Vendor(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'purchase/allVendor.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = categoryModel.objects.all()
        categoryId = self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory')
        vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(
            vendorcategory__category_id=categoryId
        )
        args = {'categories': categories, 'selectedCategory': categoryId, 'vendors': vendors}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

`vendorselect` makes not much sense, since that is a collection of `VendorCategory`s, not `Vendor`s.

Comment: It's `.objects`, not `.Object`.

Comment: it show the error  at Vendor.objects.filter. unresolved attribute  reference ' objects' for class Vendor

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: is your `Vendor` the name of the model, since in your view, you all of a sudden use `VendorModel`...

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: then you should use `VendorModel`, but I would really advise to rename the `Vendor` view to `VendorView` or something similar, since this will start introducing a lot of confusion.

Comment: Thank u so much. Can you answer my one more question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776919/how-can-store-multiple-checkbox-value-to-single-user